# Error on installing awscli in 64 bit windows 10 and Python 3.7

Tags: windows-10, amazon-web-services, python3

I have tried both msi and pip installation for awscli for windows 10, python 3.7. I am getting the error

> 'File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\aws.cmd", line 50, in
>
> import awscli.clidriver
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awscli''.

The pip installations I tried were pip install awscli,

pip install awscli --upgrade --user. All of them were giving the same error. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried to add %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts in environment path variable? Check the guide below about install awscli step by step.https://github.com/arsho/installation/tree/master/awscli_installation

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I solved the issue. I was trying MSI for 64-bit windows which didn't work. Also, my pip installations didn't work. I tried AWS CLI set up file from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html which automatically installed the correct version. This worked though I am not sure what went wrong before.